# Bigquery comparing dates and using a case when statement

Tags: datetime, case, google-bigquery

I currently have the following case statement:

```
CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP)>=TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP('03-14-2016 00:00:00')) THEN 'afterChanges' ELSE 'beforeChanges' END AS beforeOrAfter
```

I've also tried variations:

```
CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP>TIMESTAMP('03-14-2016 00:00:00') THEN 'afterChanges' ELSE 'beforeChanges' END AS beforeOrAfter

CASE WHEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP('03-14-2016 00:00:00')),0) >0 THEN 'afterChanges' ELSE 'beforeChanges' END AS beforeOrAfter
```

However, I always get the else ("beforeChanges") regardless of the original TIMESTAMP. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

All should work as below
Nore use of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` instead of just `TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) >= TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP('2016-03-04 00:00:00')) THEN 'afterChanges' 
    ELSE 'beforeChanges' 
  END AS beforeOrAfter1,
  CASE 
    WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= TIMESTAMP('2016-03-04 00:00:00') THEN 'afterChanges' 
    ELSE 'beforeChanges' 
  END AS beforeOrAfter2,
  CASE 
    WHEN CURRENT_DATE() >= DATE('2016-03-04 00:00:00') THEN 'afterChanges' 
    ELSE 'beforeChanges' 
  END AS beforeOrAfter3,
```